# ng serve - This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular ^13.0.0

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular-cli

I got a problem i do not understand why it is happening

I tried to start my Angular applikation wiht `ng serve` and this is happening:
[Angular Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2erV.png)

But if I check my versions everything seems to be fine ?!

[np informations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd83j.png)

More Informations:

1. OS: Raspberry PI OS on Raspberry PI 3 model B
2. I tried the upgrade thing, but it did not work

Thanks for every answer.

**Update:** Tried it with `npm install -g @angular/cli@12`. Did not work. Still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade you local Angular CLI version

```
rm -rf node_modules 
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm i
```

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
 ng --version
```

Update your original question with the results.

This is likely your global version needs to be downgraded

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@12
```